# How do I get an FAA okay for a private runway?

Tags: runways, faa

The county I'd like to put a private runway (for my use only) in doesn't require any special permits because the property is zoned Agricultural, BUT they do require some form of acknowledgement from the FAA that the FAA doesn't have a problem with it being in that location.  How do I go about getting something like that from the FAA?  Who do I contact?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably already aware that the FAA itself does not require the operator of a private airfield to receive any kind of approval from the FAA. However, there is a process in place to register a private airfield, and indeed the *notice* (not approval) is mandatory. The result of that process might satisfy your local authority.

The three FAQs starting [here](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/faq/#q3d) are pertinent. You need to file FAA Form [7480-1](https://www.faa.gov/forms/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/185334), either by mail or via the [OE / AAA system](https://oeaaa.faa.gov/oeaaa/external/portal.jsp).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I knew the FAA itself didn't require that I get their approval for a private airfield, but was wondering what I could get from them to satisfy the County Zoning.  I will check on seek to register my airstrip.  Thanks again.

Comment: You never know when having your airstrip registered might [come in handy](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/19460/8730)