# Private airstrip regulations

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, usa

Once a private airstrip has been certified, do you have to get faa approval to make changes to the runway such as adding crossings, access etc…?

Comment: If it's private it does not need certification, you just need to notify the FAA. See e.g. [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/60902/how-do-i-get-an-faa-okay-for-a-private-runway)

Comment: You don't even need to notify the FAA. Form 7480-1 is optional.

Comment: @Dave-CFII Notification is mandatory for the airport described. see below

Answer (score 2):

The only requirement for a private airfield is to notify the FAA using form [7480-1](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Form/faa-form-7480-1-notice-for-construction-2020.pdf). There are exceptions for otherwise regulated (these would not be private), temporary (less than 30 days), and intermittent (less than 3 days/week for less than one year) VFR use of an site that is not an airport. What you describe is a permament, civil, private use airport so you have to notify 90 days before activating or making a change.

> Title 14 Code of Federal Regulations Part 157 requires all persons to notify the FAA at least 90 days
> before construction, alteration, activation, deactivation, or change to the status or use of a civil or joint-use
> (civil/military) airport. (As used herein, the term “airport” means any Landing or Takeoff Area, e.g. Airport,
> Heliport, Vertiport, Gliderport, Seaplane Base, Ultralight Flightpark, or Balloonport.)
> Notice is not required for:
>
> 1. An airport subject to conditions of a Federal agreement that requires an approved current airport
>    layout plan to be on file with the Federal Aviation Administration.
> 2. Establishment of a temporary airport at which operations will be conducted under visual flight rule
>    (VFR) and will be used for less than 30 days with no more than 10 operations per day.
> 3. Intermittent use of a site that is not an established airport, which is used for less than one year
>    and at which flight operations will be conducted only under VFR. (Intermittent use means the use
>    of the site for no more than 3 days in any one week and for no more than 10 operations per day.)